# Jquery Loading image on Page for specific Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Div which which has an Image Loader image. I want to display that image in div once I call price calculation function the image should be displayed on whole page. Please help me

```
<div class="Progress_Layout" style="display:none">
    <div class="Progress_Content">
        <div>
            <img src="@Url.FilePath(FileTypes.IMAGES, "loader", "10271456A2B3")" style="vertical-align: middle" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Progress_Text">
            @DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("pleaseWait")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Jquery function which is called when price is calculated.

```
function CalculatePrice() {
  var req, parameters, datasend, prodlist;

  LOADING = setInterval(function () {
    $('.objprice', prodlist).html(LOADINGIMG);
  }, 5);

  LOADING = setInterval(function () {
    $("body").html($(".Progress_Layout"));
  }, 5);

  var querystring = "?" + BASIC_PARA + "&" + GetPriceCalculationQueryString() + "&filter=" + FILTER + "&sort=1&FilterChange=0&cacheprod=0";
  if (PAGE_TYPE < 3) {
    querystring = querystring + "&dumy=1",
      datasend = "";
  } else {
    req = {
      RefID: REFIDLIST
    };
    datasend = JSON.stringify(req);
    datasend = encodeURIComponent(datasend);
  }

  URL_QUERYSTRING = querystring;
  UpdateLabels();
  Searchcontrol(2);

  if (ISREFID == "" && LANDWITHPRICE == false) {
    smoothScroll('prodlistinsp', 300);
  }

  parameters = "prodrq=" + datasend;

  if (document.domain.indexOf("localhost") != -1 || document.domain.indexOf("tenbook") != -1) {
    makeRequest(TENWEB_PATH + "/inspiration/PriceCalculatorPage.aspx" + querystring, parameters);
  } else {
    makeRequest("http://" + document.domain + "/" + PROXYPAGE + querystring, parameters);
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to display a loader image with overlay on calling CalculatePrice and hide once process completed, right?

Comment: Yes Prakash you are right.

Comment: From where are you calling your calculation method? And is it taking enough time that you require loader for it?

Comment: yes approximately 1 sec in the meantime I want to display the loader along with the page as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by following structure:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loadingImage"></div>
<div id="loadingOverlay"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#loadingImage {
    background: url(http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/17.gif)
        no-repeat center center;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 11111;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    display: none;
}

#loadingOverlay {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1; 
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**JS:** Call `showLoader()` at the start of your `calculatePrice()`, then call hideLoader on specified timeout.

```
function calculatePrice(){
    showLoader();
    setTimeout(hideLoader, 1000);
}

function showLoader(){
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('loadingOverlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideLoader(){
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('loadingOverlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ttxmz7s/1/)

Comment: @Passionate Programmer, Is it what you want?